# Sending emails with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, send

I am building a room booking system for my college and I would like to send out an email when a teacher books a room to remind them. I have found one on the internet at this link:

http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=377

But when I try and use that code I get an error: "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'"

Can someone give me the low down of how to do this?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not look at the example on the [`SmtpMail` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx) if you want to know how to use that class?

Note that that API is now obsolete though - you should look at the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace and in particular the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class. Again, there are examples in the documentation.